# How one can I delete a binary file in the /bin directory via the command line?

Tags: go

I run command `go install` in `$HOME/go/src/hello/` that binary file get in catalog `$HOME/go/bin`, then run `go clean`, but binary file don't remove.

How one can I delete a binary file in the /bin directory via the command line?

Output `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/stavanger/go/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/stavanger/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build610113564=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

`.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
```

Comment: Nowhere does it say `go clean` should remove binaries from your path. From the docs: `clean removes object files from package source directories`. See `go help clean` for a list of files it removes.

Comment: @JimB: Nowhere! Really! For example, `go help clean`: "The -i flag causes clean to remove the corresponding installed archive or binary (what 'go install' would create)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The -i flag causes clean to remove the corresponding installed archive
>   or binary (what ['go build' or] 'go install' would create).

Try the `go clean -i` flag?

---

```
$ go help clean
usage: go clean [-i] [-r] [-n] [-x] [-cache] [-testcache] [build flags] [packages]

Clean removes object files from package source directories.
The go command builds most objects in a temporary directory,
so go clean is mainly concerned with object files left by other
tools or by manual invocations of go build.

Specifically, clean removes the following files from each of the
source directories corresponding to the import paths:

    _obj/            old object directory, left from Makefiles
    _test/           old test directory, left from Makefiles
    _testmain.go     old gotest file, left from Makefiles
    test.out         old test log, left from Makefiles
    build.out        old test log, left from Makefiles
    *.[568ao]        object files, left from Makefiles

    DIR(.exe)        from go build
    DIR.test(.exe)   from go test -c
    MAINFILE(.exe)   from go build MAINFILE.go
    *.so             from SWIG

In the list, DIR represents the final path element of the
directory, and MAINFILE is the base name of any Go source
file in the directory that is not included when building
the package.

The -i flag causes clean to remove the corresponding installed
archive or binary (what 'go install' would create).

The -n flag causes clean to print the remove commands it would execute,
but not run them.

The -r flag causes clean to be applied recursively to all the
dependencies of the packages named by the import paths.

The -x flag causes clean to print remove commands as it executes them.

The -cache flag causes clean to remove the entire go build cache.

The -testcache flag causes clean to expire all test results in the
go build cache.

For more about build flags, see 'go help build'.

For more about specifying packages, see 'go help packages'.
$
```

---

> [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Remove object files](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remove_object_files)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go clean [-i] [-r] [-n] [-x] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Clean removes object files from package source directories. The go
>   command builds most objects in a temporary directory, so go clean is
>   mainly concerned with object files left by other tools or by manual
>   invocations of go build.
>
> Specifically, clean removes the following files from each of the
>   source directories corresponding to the import paths:
>
> ```
> _obj/            old object directory, left from Makefiles
> _test/           old test directory, left from Makefiles
> _testmain.go     old gotest file, left from Makefiles
> test.out         old test log, left from Makefiles
> build.out        old test log, left from Makefiles
> *.[568ao]        object files, left from Makefiles
>
> DIR(.exe)        from go build
> DIR.test(.exe)   from go test -c
> MAINFILE(.exe)   from go build MAINFILE.go
> *.so             from SWIG
> ```
>
> In the list, DIR represents the final path element of the directory,
>   and MAINFILE is the base name of any Go source file in the directory
>   that is not included when building the package.
>
> The -i flag causes clean to remove the corresponding installed archive
>   or binary (what 'go install' would create).
>
> The -n flag causes clean to print the remove commands it would
>   execute, but not run them.
>
> The -r flag causes clean to be applied recursively to all the
>   dependencies of the packages named by the import paths.
>
> The -x flag causes clean to print remove commands as it executes them.
>
> For more about build flags, see 'go help build'.
>
> For more about specifying packages, see 'go help packages'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm convinced that when executing `go clean` in certain case somehow the binary file is delete, but I could don't recreate this behavior any more. I realize that this is not documented, but the fact remains. I'm confused.

Comment: **`go clean -i` is what I need, the absolute answer to my question! Thanks a lot!**